# Zoom every point in chart by mouse over

Tags: c#

I have a chart on my c# windows application.
I want to zoom every point of chart  when mouse on them.
like google map

I mean I don't want zoom all part of chart
I want zoom just specefic point like google map

code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int[] myArrayX = new int[5];
        double[] myArrayY = new double[5];
        int lastX = -1;
        double lastY = -0.6;
        double xmax;

        Graph.Chart chart;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseWheel);
        }

        void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0)
                {
                    double xMin = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    double xMax = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                    double yMin = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    double yMax = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                    double posXStart = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 2;
                    double posXFinish = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 2;
                    double posYStart = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 2;
                    double posYFinish = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 2;

                    chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                    chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
                }
                else if (e.Delta < 0)
                {
                    ZoomOut();
                }

            }
            catch { }


        }

        private void ZoomOut()
        {
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        }



        void CreateNewGraph()
        {
            // Create new Graph
            chart = new Graph.Chart();


            chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 185);


            chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 500);


            chart.ChartAreas.Add("draw");




            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Maximum = 20;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Interval = 1;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum = -0.4;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum = 1;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval = 0.2;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;


            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].BackColor = Color.Black;



            var series = chart.Series.Add("Test");


            chart.Series["Test"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;


            chart.Series["Test"].Color = Color.Yellow;


            chart.Series["Test"].BorderWidth = 3;


            chart.Legends.Add("MyLegend");
            chart.Legends["MyLegend"].BorderColor = Color.YellowGreen;

            // Set automatic zooming
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

            // Set automatic scrolling 
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;

            // Allow user selection for Zoom
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

            //chart.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(chart_MouseWheel);
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateNewGraph();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillarray();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1)
            {
                chart.Series["Test"].Points.AddXY(myArrayX[i - 1], myArrayY[i - 1]);
                xmax = myArrayX[i - 1];
            }

            if (xmax >= 20)
            {
                chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
                chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, xmax);
            }

            Controls.Add(this.chart);

        }

        public void fillarray()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1)
            {
                lastX = lastX + 1;
                myArrayX[i - 1] = lastX;

            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i += 1)
            {
                lastY = lastY + 0.2;
                myArrayY[i - 1] = lastY;

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: you are using `ms chart` or some othr commercial chart?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you use the "standard" (since .NET 4.0) Charting Lib which is in the namespace System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting. You can implement custom interactivity (zoom when mouse does this or that). MSDN is a good start and GIYF.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There are also a lot of [examples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418) around the web.

good luck!